# could not broadcast input array from shape (13,160) into shape (13) while using sklearn normaliser

Tags: machine-learning, audio-recognition

I am try to normalize my features with this code:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaler  = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
X_normaliser= scaler.fit_transform(features_mfcc)
print(len(X_normaliser))
```

But I am getting this error:

```
could not broadcast input array from shape (13,160) into shape (13)
```

And the format of features_mfcc is:

```
[array([[-9.0505310e+02, -9.0509668e+02, -9.0453448e+02, ...,
        -9.0509668e+02, -9.0509668e+02, -9.0465082e+02],
       [ 6.1652310e-02,  0.0000000e+00,  7.9452515e-01, ...,
         0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  6.3048005e-01],
       [ 6.1638385e-02,  0.0000000e+00,  7.9280442e-01, ...,
         0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  6.3033760e-01],
       ...,
       [ 6.1193265e-02,  0.0000000e+00,  7.3878741e-01, ...,
         0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  6.2578565e-01],
       [ 6.1096039e-02,  0.0000000e+00,  7.2723877e-01, ...,
         0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  6.2479138e-01],
       [ 6.0989607e-02,  0.0000000e+00,  7.1469700e-01, ...,
         0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  6.2370300e-01]], dtype=float32), array([[-9.0509668e+02, -9.0509668e+02, -9.0509668e+02, ...,
        -8.5759808e+02, -8.5833606e+02, -8.5879651e+02],
       [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, ...,
         4.4959282e+01,  4.3793659e+01,  4.0313797e+01],
       [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, ...,
         1.4145700e+01,  1.7536686e+01,  9.3698139e+00],
       ...,
       [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, ...,
         1.4837956e+00,  1.4310437e+00,  6.0682583e+00],
       [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, ...,
        -3.7497518e+00, -2.3724816e+00,  4.0706646e-01],
       [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, ...,
        -2.3869281e+00, -1.9489181e+00, -1.6806124e+00]], dtype=float32), array([[-905.0967   , -905.0967   , -905.0967   , ..., -902.40015  ,
        -901.81915  , -900.8688   ],
       [   0.       ,    0.       ,    0.       , ...,    3.8109207,
           4.632819 ,    5.901035 ],
       [   0.       ,    0.       ,    0.       , ...,    3.803548 ,
           4.6260605,    5.6991043],
       ...,
       [   0.       ,    0.       ,    0.       , ...,    3.5749695,
           4.4136033,    3.6421943],
       [   0.       ,    0.       ,    0.       , ...,    3.5268202,
           4.368108 ,    3.6132731],
       [   0.       ,    0.       ,    0.       , ...,    3.4748278,
           4.318678 ,    3.6719213]], dtype=float32), array([[-9.0450629e+02, -9.0407922e+02, -9.0477014e+02, ...,
        -8.9970392e+02, -9.0248578e+02, -9.0419568e+02],
       [ 8.3469510e-01,  1.4383652e+00,  4.6172076e-01, ...,
         5.6700068e+00,  2.9931142e+00,  1.2736886e+00],
       [ 8.3379471e-01,  1.4369218e+00,  4.6155667e-01, ...,
         2.2444835e+00,  1.8527040e+00,  1.2720714e+00],
       ...,
       [ 8.0518466e-01,  1.3911897e+00,  4.5630401e-01, ...,
         4.0884919e+00,  3.0479903e+00,  1.2209207e+00],
       [ 7.9899836e-01,  1.3813030e+00,  4.5516133e-01, ...,
         3.1457639e+00,  2.3051815e+00,  1.2098712e+00],
       [ 7.9225874e-01,  1.3705225e+00,  4.5391160e-01, ...,
         2.5792625e+00,  1.9462540e+00,  1.1978207e+00]], dtype=float32), array([[-9.0509668e+02, -9.0509668e+02, -9.0468939e+02, ...,
        -9.0480646e+02, -9.0484973e+02, -9.0509668e+02],
       [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  5.7561249e-01, ...,
         4.1038188e-01,  3.4921879e-01,  0.0000000e+00],
       [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  5.7488233e-01, ...,
         4.1028821e-01,  3.4913990e-01,  0.0000000e+00],
       ...,
       [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  5.5182308e-01, ...,
         4.0732536e-01,  3.4661859e-01,  0.0000000e+00],
       [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  5.4684269e-01, ...,
         4.0667912e-01,  3.4606788e-01,  0.0000000e+00],
       [ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  5.4140812e-01, ...,
         4.0596974e-01,  3.4546313e-01,  0.0000000e+00]], dtype=float32)]
```

Can someone help me here?

Comment: Please post a [mcve](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366988/what-does-mcve-mean) along with complete error message etc.

Comment: Your features_mfcc is three-dimensional (a list of 2d arrays); how exactly do you want the data scaled?

Comment: in this format :

Comment: array([[ 1., -1.,  2.],
       [ 2.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1., -1.]])

Comment: That's a 2d array; how do you want your 3d data dealt with?  Also, your example in the comment doesn't appear to be scaled in any meaningful way, so again: _how_ do you want the data scaled?

Answer (score 1):

Your MFCCs are a time-series, 2d representation. scikit-learn transformers like StandardScaler only works with 1d data (plus one dimension for the individual samples).
So you need to implement the standardization yourself. And then convert the data to 1d.

Or summarize the entire MFCC time series into a single vector. For example using mean/std.